# How can I edit my profile from the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, display-names, profile-picture

1. How do I change my picture?
2. How do I change my name?

Comment: Go to your profile. Click on the edit button. Voila!

Comment: @michaelpri Im using the mobile app on android I cannot find no edit option.

Comment: Specify in your question that you are on mobile.